# lnk1136 - invalid or corrupt .lib

Tags: c++, dll, .lib

I've got a little problem. I got a dll C library, a header file, and all other files needed to call this dll. I've tried calling this dll through third party programs and it is working.
However, when I try calling it directly (dynamic linking at load and using the given header file) I always get the linker error 1136 with mydll.lib.

Using the header file:

```
#include "windows.h"
#include "mydll.h"

void main() {
    bool test;
    test = CallDll("MyArg");
}
```

With code in headerfile as below:

```
extern "C" bool _stdcall CallDll(char* MyArg);
```

Using dynamic linking at load time:

```
#include "windows.h"

bool(*CallDll)(char*);
HINSTANCE h = LoadLibrary((LPCSTR)"mydll");

void main() {
    CallDll = (bool(*)(char*))GetProcAddress(h, "CallDll");
    bool test;
    test = CallDll("MyArg");
}
```

Now what did I do wrong? I doubt the mydll.lib file is broken, because if this were the issue, I couldn't access the dll with a third party program.

Comment: you have to give the DLL, not the LIB, to LoadLibrary.

Comment: The linker error message says that mydll.lib is broken.  Why do you doubt it?  Did you just copy mydll.dll to mydll.lib and hope it would work?  It won't.  Get a good one from the author or vendor.

Comment: If you use `LoadLibrary`, you don't have to link the `.lib` file

Comment: You're mixing implicit and explicit linking: read more [here](http://www.codeguru.com/cpp/cpp/cpp_mfc/tutorials/article.php/c9855/DLL-Tutorial-For-Beginners.htm)

Comment: @WouterHuysentruit Thanks for all your help, it worked when i removed the link to the .lib file in VS. Now I have another problem, the function pointer defined with typdef bool( * CallDll)(char *,double,double&) somehow only accepts one input, even thougth i specified 3, any idead what I did wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well it was a rather simple solution.

```
bool(*CallDll)(char*);
HINSTANCE h = LoadLibrary(L"mydll.dll");

void main() {
    CallDll = (bool(*)(char*))GetProcAddress(h, "CallDll");
    bool test;
    test = CallDll((char*)"MyArg");
}
```

Was all it needed...

Comment: ehm the solution has a wrong cast, this is the right one: `CallDll DoCallDll;` `DoCallDll=(bool(*)(char*))GetProcAddress(h,"CallDll");` `bool test=DoCallDll((char*)"MyArg");`